# Send message from a pthread to the main thread

Tags: c, stack

Consider the following code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>

pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
void *camera_function(void *arg)
{
    int picture[4096][4096];
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    int cnum = *(int *)arg;

    for (;;)
    {
      bool suspicious = true;
       if(suspicious)
          // send message to the parent process
         sleep(S);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
// Security process
//This will call the camera function
int main()
{
    int N = 10, S = 10;
    pthread_t CameraPids[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        int cnum = i;
        pthread_create(&CameraPids[i], NULL, camera_function, (void *)&cnum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the above there is a comment **// send message to the parent process** 
What I want to do is send some message to the parent process that is the **main** function in this case.
And the main function should print that message
How do I achieve that?

Comment: Could it be some signal we can send to the parent process? And if that signal is received  the parent process handles it

Comment: In your loop, `suspicious` is initialized to `true` on _every_ loop interation. So, you will loop _infinitely_. You're _not_ using your `cond` variable at all. What do you mean by "send message"? Do you mean `msgsnd/msgrcv`? Or, do you want to put some data in a common buffer, gated by the mutex and cond variable?

Comment: That true I have just put it as a dummy code. Because the main intention is that the threads that are created can communicate with the main() function/process. So say suspicious = function_Call()  and then if it returns true send a signal to the main process. It could be anything signal/msgsnd. What I want is that suspicious= true then the main method should print say ** vulnerability found**